# Adobe Acrobat на Linux

Tags: acrobat, linux

Есть ли Adobe Acrobat под linux на русском? Если есть, то где?

Answer (score 1):

Как [видим](http://www.adobe.com/products/acrobatpro/tech-specs.html), только Win & Mac. Под Linux не версий вообще.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант можно взять имеющийся дистрибутив Acrobat под Windows и пустить его через Wine. В сети пишут, что этот метод работает.

Answer (score 0):

А чем не устраивает куча утилит под линуксы?[Xpdf](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xpdf)

Comment: А есть аналог Acrobat'a?

Comment: о черт, акробата не знаю, я почему то про ридер подумал ^_^ну вот вариант, сам не пробовал.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install acroread
```

Для Ubuntu

Comment: На русском, сори, не до конца вопрос дочитал